# SQL Joining tables Using Spring JPA

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have some trouble with joining tables using Spring Boot JPA

I need to do this kind of joining:

**book2user — book to user

- id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
- time DATETIME NOT NULL
- type_id INT NOT NULL
- book_id INT NOT NULL
- user_id INT NOT NULL**

Here are my Entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;
private String hash;
private Date reg_time;
private Integer balance = 0;
private String name;    

// getters and setters


public class Book {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "author_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Author author;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "genre_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Genre genre;

private String title;
private String slug;
private String description;
private String priceOld;
private String price;
private String image;
private boolean is_bestseller;
private Date pub_date;
// getters and setters
```

In order to do this kind of joining I should create another entity class ??

Comment: Do you want to create a new table in the database with above schema, or do a SQL join and fetch the results?

Comment: I want to create a table (new entity class) using book and user tables' id.

Comment: It should contain book_id from Book entity and user_id from User entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
@Entity
@Table("book2user")
public class Book2User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    private LocalDateTime time;
    private Integer typeId;

    @OneToOne
    private Book book;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") //optional, if the name of the table and field matches.
    private User user;

}
```

Comment: Should I also add @OneToOne annotation to Book and User classes??

Comment: I mean is it be related to this class or to User class?    Very confused with joining tables :)

Comment: It depends, if you want to fetch this entity/information when you fetch Book you can define that relationship. It all depends on how we want to fetch and use the entity in our business logic. For example, if we don't always want to fetch book, only its id we could have defined the it as `private Integer bookId;` instead of `@OneToOne private Book book;`